# str.extract within a function

Tags: python, regex, string, function, extract

I want to create a function and extract with str.extract the following string from my dataframe: 100 milliliter

But I am unable to create the function. It does work without the function.

I tried:

```
def extract(str):

    pattern = str.extract('\d+ milliliter, str)

return (str)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please make sure that your include code is identical to what is in your IDE or text editor. Best is to copy the code and paste it between backticks, see the [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

```
def extract(df):
   pattern = '(\d*\s*milliliter)'
    return df.str.extract(pattern)

extract(df['column_name'])
```

Comment: I tried this code but it's giving me a key error with the column -> "KeyError: 'prediction_title'". Prediction_title is the name of the column.

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the correct column? 'prediction_title' and 'Prediction_title' are two different columns.

Comment: Yes I referred to prediction_title. Didn't mean to write "Prediction_title" above. I am receiving this error now: ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

Comment: That is my bad as I forgot to put the pattern into brackets. Made an edit. Also made some testing on my end and the function works. If you need the specific string: '100 milliliter' instead of `'(\d+ milliliter)'` use `'(100 milliliter)'`

Comment: Nice! The code works, but I think the regex is in general not working. I had this issue with another code as well. I am not getting any result if I try to extract "\d+ milliliter". But I do get result when I am only extracting "milliliter". Do you know any solution for this? I would usually use regex=True, but doesn't work in a function as well

Comment: If its still just not finding the capture group try `'(\d*\s*milliliter)'`

Comment: Works!! So '(\d*\s*milliliter)' will also extract numbers like 1.5 and not just whole numbers right? And what if I want to add extract liter, centiliter etc. as well, can I just add these behind the current code and split it with a '|'?

Comment: Yes, '(\d*\s*milliliter)' will also extract numbers like 1.5. To extract liter, centiliter etc., you can add them behind the current code, separated by a '|'. For example, `'(\d*\s*milliliter|\d*\s*liter|\d*\s*centiliter)'`.

Comment: Works like a champ! Thank you so much Kylar!!

Comment: Would you know how I can concat columns and drop the rest. Within a "def" function?
Something like this:
df['new_column'] = df['column1] + df['column2'] + df['column3']
df.drop(['column1', 'column2, 'column3'], axis=1, inplace=True)